# Websocket on firefox webgl

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, unity-game-engine, websocket, unity-webgl

I have an issue with my game. I am working on a game in Unity3D 5, in WebGL. The game connect to a server using web socket with an address that looks like this:

> wss://serveraddress:8443/moreaddress

It is using a javascript implementation to connect to the server. The javascript looks like this :

```
var WSClient = {
    socket: null,
    url: null,

    connect: function(host) {
        if ('WebSocket' in window) {
            this.socket = new WebSocket(host);
        } else if ('MozWebSocket' in window) {
            this.socket = new MozWebSocket(host);
        } else {
            Console.log('Error: WebSocket is not supported by this browser.');
            return;
        }

        this.socket.onopen = function()
        {
            SendMessage("WebSocketManager","OnOpenWebSocket");
        };

        this.socket.onclose = function() {
            SendMessage("WebSocketManager","OnCloseWebSocket");
        };

        this.socket.onmessage = function(message) {
            if(typeof message == "string"){
                SendMessage('WebSocketManager','OnMessageReceived', message);
            }
        };
    },

    initialize: function(url) {
        if (typeof url !== "undefined")
            this.url = url;

        if (this.url == null) {
            Console.log('Info: Initialize without an URL');
            return;
        }

        this.connect(this.url);
    },

    sendMessage: function(msg) {
        if (msg != '') {
            this.socket.send(msg);
        }
    },

    close: function() {
        this.socket.close();
    }
};
```

The SendMessage function is just something to call a function in Unity. So basically what is happening to me is after my game connect to the server, the `onOpen()` function gets called, then calls my `OnOpenWebSocket()` function from Unity, which then tries to send a message to the server to login, the server receives the message and attempts to send me an answer, but all I am getting in my `onMessage()` function is this message : `{"isTrusted":true}.`

This happens on Firefox, but works perfectly fine on Chrome. On Chrome I am getting the right message from my server. And there is nowhere in the server a place where `isTrusted` is written.

I am using Firefox 33.0. And Chrome 39.0.2171.95

I looked in the `about:config` of firefox, and the `websocket` are enabled.

Anyone has an idea on what could cause this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when experimenting with websockets. I changed my code to

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3331"); // some url
ws.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log(event.data);
}
```

Then it worked on firefox! The onmessage callback is of type EventListener and receives a MessageEvent as argument, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket.